# NSFileManager change file owner/permissions

Tags: objective-c, macos, file, permissions, plist

I have an application which running under root and changes some file which was created by user.
The problem is that after editing file using my application it saves succesfully but changes owner of file. 
So before editing file was:

```
-rw-------@ 1 myusername  wheel  2418 Jun 18 18:29 myfile.plist
```

After editing:

```
-rw-------@ 1 root  wheel  2418 Jun 18 18:29 myfile.plist
```

Here is a code how I edit a file:

```
NSMutableDictionary* myFile = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"myFile.plist"];
[myFile setObject:@"some text" forKey:@"some key"];
BOOL result = [myFile writeToFile:@"myFile.plist" atomically:YES];
```

I need to keep file's owner even after editing using app under root. 
How can I solve the problem above?

EDIT: I tried the following code and it return successful result but doesn't change permissions:

```
NSDictionary *properties = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:@"myfile.plist"
                                                                            error:nil];

NSMutableDictionary *newProperties = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:properties];
[newProperties setObject:@"myusername" forKey:NSFileOwnerAccountName];

NSError *error = nil;

BOOL result = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] setAttributes:newProperties
                                               ofItemAtPath:@"myfile.plist"
                                                      error:&error];
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe for permissions only NSNumber objects are accepted for `attributesOfItemAtPath`. Try using AccountID instead: (**NSFileOwnerAccountID** and/or **NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID**):

```
NSMutableDictionary *newProperties = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:properties];
            [newProperties setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:NSFileOwnerAccountID];
```

*From Apples Documentation*:

> NSFilePosixPermissions value must be initialized with
>   the code representing the POSIX file-permissions bit pattern, in which
>   the corresponding value is an NSNumber object.

Reference: [NSFileOwnerAccountID](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setAttributes:ofItemAtPath:error:` method of `NSFileManager` with an attribute of `NSFileImmutable`:

```
NSDictionary* attribs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSFileImmutable];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager]  setAttributes: attribs ofItemAtPath:@"/path/to/file" error:nil];
```

Hope this helps !